# Is this making a strong reference cycle when creating cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reference

I have an array of type `Task`, which is a class.  In `cellForRowAt`, I create my cell.  The first thing I do is see which task to use by accessing the array with the `indexPath`. Is the result of that a strong reference cycle?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentBudgetTask = currentBudgetTaskForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? BudgetCell else {
        return BudgetCell()
    }

    configureCell(cell, for: currentBudgetTask)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Do you  mean _reference cycle_ (_circular reference_) with **_strong reference_**? Swift holds strong reference for all class instances.

Comment: Yes I mean am I creating a reference cycle.

Comment: Simple rule: No closure, no retain cycle. By the way, you don't need the `guard`, this method returns always a valid cell `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BudgetCell`. If an crash occurs it reveals a design error (the cell is not designed properly).

Comment: If I don't use the guard I have to force unwrap the cell.  Isn't that bad practice?  Thank you for the explanation about closures.

Comment: The return type of `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` is non-Optional. (It may be confusing but `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` returns Optional and you may need guard or other nil checking.) So casting non-Optional to Optional and use it in `guard`-`let` is sort of redundant and worse than bad practice.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.  I was using `as?` when I should have been using `as!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No,** as you are simply passing an *index path*, which contains two integers, to a function.

The index path does **not** hold a reference for the class (or the cell itself) in any means, so this is safe to do.